# php file_exists() only works once in the same function

Tags: php, file-rename, file-exists

I have a php function that renames two separate image files from a temporary to permanent path after first confirming that the temporary path exists.

When it checks for the fist file it works fine but, for some reason, the second file never passes the if(file_exists()) even though I can confirm with 100% certainty that the file path being checked does, in fact, exist.

The image files have different names but the codes are otherwise structured exactly the same so I can't see why one would work and the other wouldn't.

```
if(file_exists('temp/'.strtolower($option['image1']))){
   $path1 = 'images/'.strtolower($option['image1']); // upload directory
   $tmp1 = 'temp/'.strtolower($option['image1']);
   if(rename($tmp1, $path1)){
      $error = 0;
   }else{
      $error = 4;
   }
}
if(file_exists('temp/'.strtolower($option['image2']))){
   $path2 = 'images/'.strtolower($option['image2']); // upload directory
   $tmp2 = 'temp/'.strtolower($option['image2']); 
   if(rename($tmp2, $path2)){
     $error = 0;
   }else{
     $error = 5;
   }
}
```

Is there an issue with calling file_exists() twice? How else can I check for both paths?

**Edit**
As per Marco-A's suggestion, I added clearstatcache(); between the two if/then blocks and it worked like a charm.

Comment: I think we'll need a [mcve] on this one.

Comment: Why you `strtolower()`?

Comment: Have a look into file permissions and `clearstatcache()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only two possibilities (if you're absolutely sure the file path exists) I'm seeing are either 1.) a stat cache problem (you can clear the cache with [`clearstatcache`](https://www.php.net/clearstatcache)) or 2.) a permission issue. Consider this:

```
$ touch /tmp/locked/file
$ php is_file_test.php
$ bool(true)
$ chmod -x /tmp/locked
$ php is_file_test.php
$ bool(false)
```

So it might be, that the parent directory of that file doesn't have the `x` (executable) permission bit set. This prevents any process from iterating and accessing the directory's content.

Comment: You're right, it was the stat cache. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @CatieCamastro You're welcome! I remember when it bit me the first time. It's one of these things that you learn once and then won't forget :-)

Answer (score 0):

The uploaded file names can have uppercase characters. If you use `strtolower` in the `file_exists` function, you probably wouldn't be looking for the original file path.

```php
if(file_exists('temp/' . strtolower($option['image']))){
    // ...
}
```

Should be changed to:

```php
if(file_exists('temp/' . $option['image'])){
    // ...
}
```

Comment: The question seems directly to address the problem that @marco-a points out in the part of his answer. The use of `strtolower` shouldn't have any effect since it is used in both cases.

Comment: @schmauch You are right if the file name consists of lowercase letters in both cases. However, my answer is the problem's solution when image2 has uppercase letters, and image1 hasn't.

Comment: I did consider this but the function that initially uploads the file to the temp folder also uses strtolower() and confirmed that it works. Sorry, I should have included that.